# Advice for learning how to use httr to access API

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to learn how to use `httr` to access an SMS service's API. The package documentation is helpful, but I think I lack an understanding of some important higher level concepts. Could someone point me to a good tutorial for using `httr`?

In case it is helpful in directing me to the right type of resource, here is an example of a url I am trying to use from the service provider's API documentation (account is not active):

```
http://sms.shujaa.mobi/sendsms?username=info%40shujaa.co.ke&password=info&account=developer&source=2024&destination=254717555555&message=This%20is%20a%20test.&network=safaricom
```

My first inclination was to define each object and then paste together the string.

```
library(httr)

url <- "http://sms.shujaa.mobi/sendsms"
username <- "info%40shujaa.co.ke"                    
password <- "info&account"                   
account <- "developer"
source <- "2024"                        
destination <- "254717555555"
message <- "This%20is%20a%20test."
network <- "safaricom"

send <- paste0(url, "?", "username=", username, "&password=", password, "&account=",
           account, "&source=", source, "&destination=", destination, "&message=", message,
           "&network=", network)

POST(send)
```

I don't think this is the correct approach. I think I should be using some of the arguments of POST to modify the url with the necessary info, but I'm not seeing the bigger picture. I think an example or two might help me move in the right direction. The included demos don't seem to address my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start getting to grips with OAuth, and use keys, secrets, tokens etc in order to have full use of all API features that they provide...

`httr` is the correct package to use though...

Please have a look at my answer for another API connection

[How to use OAuth at XING with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198411/how-to-use-oauth-at-xing-with-r/14398732#14398732)

Hope that helps...it would be more useful if you let us know what the service is so that we can better assist you...

Comment: Thanks, @h.l.m. I will take a look. In the meantime, the service is called [Shujaa SMS Gateway](http://sms.shujaa.mobi/faq.jsp). Their API documentation is [here](http://shujaa.co.ke:81/tmp/sms/Shujaa%20SMS%20Gateway%20Developer%20Guide.pdf).

Comment: Ah, I just checked the service...its not an OAuth style authorisation API...so the method you used is about as good as its going to get...(I had jumped the gun a bit as I had assumed it was a bluechip kinda API, most of which use OAuth authentication...)